# Lagrangian for Non-inertial Frame

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, reference-frames

**Context**

Let us consider two reference frames: $S$ and $S'$. $S'$ is rotating with respect to $S$ with an angular velocity $\vec{\omega}$ about a rotation axis $MOM'$. The origins of $S$ and $S'$ are $O$ and $O'$ and they coincide.

Let's say, I want to write a Lagrangian for a free particle of mass $m$ in $S$:

$$L = \frac{1}{2} m \dot{\textbf{r}}^2 \tag{1}$$

Then in $S'$:

$$L = \frac{1}{2} m |\dot{\textbf{r}}' + \vec{\omega} \times \textbf{r}'|^2 \tag{2}$$
where I have used the transformation formula for velocity:
$$(\dot{\textbf{r}})_S = (\dot{\textbf{r}})_{S'} + \vec{\omega} \times \textbf{r}.$$

If I want to evaluate the RS of eq. (2), then I have the following two options:

**Option 1**

\begin{eqnarray}
|\textbf{A} + \textbf{B}|^2 &=& |(A_x + B_x)\hat{x} + (A_y + B_y)\hat{y}|^2 \\ &=& \left(\sqrt{(A_x + B_x)^2 + (A_y + B_y)^2}\right)^2 &=& (A_x + B_x)^2 + (A_y + B_y)^2.
\end{eqnarray}

**Option 2**

\begin{eqnarray}
|\textbf{A} + \textbf{B}|^2 &=& |(\textbf{A} + \textbf{B})^2| \\
&=& |A^2 + B^2 + 2\textbf{A}\cdot\textbf{B}| \\
&\color{red}{\leq}& |A^2 + B^2| + |2\textbf{A}\cdot\textbf{B}| \\
&\color{red}{\leq}& |A^2| + |B^2| + 2|\textbf{A}\cdot\textbf{B}| \\
&=& A_x^2 + A_y^2 + B_x^2 + B_y^2 + 2A_xB_x + 2A_yB_y. 
\end{eqnarray}

**Question**

I'm confused about the three $\leq$ in Option 2. Some Physics textbooks uses Option 1, but if I want to use Option 2, then how can I mathematically justify for the $\leq$ symbols?

**Edit**

The last line in the Option 2 should be the following.

\begin{eqnarray}
&& A_x^2 + A_y^2 + B_x^2 + B_y^2 + 2|A_xB_x + A_yB_y| \\
&\color{red}{\leq}& A_x^2 + A_y^2 + B_x^2 + B_y^2 + 2|A_xB_x| + 2|A_yB_y|
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Why there is a down vote?

Comment: I guess we have to just deal with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the [triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality). The sum of magnitudes is always at least as large as the magnitude of the sum: $$\left|A+B\right|\le \left|A\right| + \left|B\right|$$

The inequality is not necessary here, since both $A^2$ and $B^2$ are positive, so that term is an equality.

The last line of your formula is not correct, though. In general $$ |\mathbf{A}\cdot\mathbf{B}|\ne A_xB_x+A_yB_y$$

For instance, the left-hand side is obviously positive definite, whereas the right-hand side need not be.

Which makes sense: you shouldn't get the same expression if you compute it exactly versus if you use inequalities along the way.

Comment: What do you mean by computing 'exactly'?

Comment: @far.westerner Meaning without inequalities

Comment: @Chirs: How do I know that the Option 1 precedes Option 2 in the given context?

Comment: @far.westerner I don't follow your question.

Comment: As you have pointed out my mistake, it is evident that the two final expressions in Option 1 and 2 are not the same. Now that textbooks use Option 1, I would like to know why one should not follow  the Option 2?

Comment: @far.westerner Because of the inequalities, basically. Option 1 gives you the correct expression, while the other gives you an upper bound. There's not really an option- "option 2" doesn't give you the actual result.